# I keep getting positional argument errors when trying to use a method from another class in a new class

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, physics

I have a ball class defined in Python, as follows, which is initialised with a mass = 1, radius = 1, and then we can set its position and velocity vectors as 2d numpy arrays.

```
class Ball():
    
    def __init__(self, pos = np.array([0,0]), vel = np.array([0,0]), mass = 1, radius = 1):
        self.mass = mass
        self.radius = radius
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = vel
```

I also have a daughter class of Ball, called Container, which is essentially a large ball of radius 10, as follows:

```
class Container(Ball):
    def __init__(self, radius = 10):
        self.radius = radius
```

The ball class also has three methods which I would like to use in a new class, called Simulation. These methods are defined in the ball class, as follows (with the parameter other simply being another ball that the self ball collides with):

```
    def move(self, dt):
        self.dt = dt
        return np.add((self.pos),(np.dot((self.vel),self.dt)))
    
    def time_to_collision(self, other):
        self.other = other
        self.posdif = np.subtract(self.pos, other.pos)
        self.veldif = np.subtract(self.vel, other.vel)
        self.posdif = np.subtract(self.pos, other.pos)
        self.veldif = np.subtract (self.vel, other.vel)
        self.raddif = self.radius - other.radius
        return (-2*np.dot(self.posdif, self.veldif) + np.sqrt(4*(np.dot(self.posdif, self.veldif)**2)-4*np.dot(self.veldif, self.veldif)*(np.dot(self.posdif, self.posdif)-np.dot(self.raddif, self.raddif))))/(2*np.dot(self.veldif, self.veldif))

    def collide(self, other):
        self.other = other
        return self.vel - (np.dot(self.veldif, self.posdif)*self.posdif)/(np.dot(self.posdif,self.posdif))
```

Apologies for the long calculation, but I do not think that calculation line is relevant to the problem necessarily, just included it for completeness. These methods, `move`, `time_to_collision` and `collide` are to be used in another class, Simulation. The simulation class is defined as follows:

```
class Simulation():
    def __init__(self, ball = Ball(), container = Container()):
        self._container = container
        self._ball = ball

    def next_collision(self):
        return self._ball.move(self._ball.time_to_collision(self._ball, self._container))
```

The simulation class aims to be initialised with a Ball object, and a Container object. It then has a method, `next_collision`, (with the only parameter being self) which uses the methods `time_to_collision` to work out the time between the collision of the ball and the container, and then it will use `move` to move the system to that moment in time, and then perform the collision using `collide`. The situation looks like this if a visualisation might help:
[image]

I have tried to achieve this in my `next_collision(self):` method, but I am always getting the same type error:

```
TypeError: time_to_collision() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: In `next_collision()` you are calling `self._ball.time_to_collision()` with two arguments `self._ball` and  `self._container`, while you should use only the second one:  `self._ball.time_to_collision(self._container)`.

Comment: Will that account for a collision between the container AND the ball?

Comment: `self._ball.time_to_collision()` is a bound method. When you call it the argument `self` in the definition of `time_to_collision()` automatically becomes `self._ball`.

Comment: Beyond the issue you're asking about, here are some other problems I see that will cause you trouble later: You're not initializing all of the attributes that `Ball` methods will expect in `Container.__init__`. You probably want to be calling `super().__init__` with some set of arguments, so that `Ball.__init__` can take care of them for you. A further issue is that you're using mutable default arguments, which is usually a bad idea in Python (see [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) for details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `next_collision` method takes just two arguments and you are passing three, just like an error says.

The `self` argument is passed automatically when you call the method on an object. So you should use it as `self._ball.time_to_collision(self._container)` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to OOP and am still getting used to it.